# Mod rewrite format for blog URL with post and name in title

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

understand how to make e.g. `blog.php` rewrite to just blog.

But I can't understand what I  need to do when rewriting a dynamic URL.

The URL normally looks like so:

```
<a href='newspost.php?id=$postID&$blogtitleURL'></a>
```

This works fine as it should, but i want it to look more friendly.

E.g. `newspost/5/Blog_title`.

Is this possible? Also how if it is, do I go about making a variable using `$_GET`?

I normally use this for the rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^apage apage.php [L]
```

What should I be doing for the URL provided?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually do it the other way around. Use php to create the link "pretty" and then use htaccess to rewrite it to split apart the get variables. THe end user sees the "pretty" url

Comment: @user2921557 Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /newspost\.php\?id=(.*)&title=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /newspost/%2/%3\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^newspost/(.*)/(.*)$ /newspost.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```